# IIS bottleneck?

Tags: asp.net, iis, grinder

I have 3 machines - one which is IIS, one with a database and one from which I test the efficiency of my application - which means:
Using The Grinder I run 1000 instances of my application (hosted on the IIS and operating with the database on the machine with SQL Server). And using perfmon I observe that there really are 1000 requests.

BUT the problem is that connecting to this application (IIS) from another computer is very slow. I suppose there is some bottleneck on the IIS side but I cannot find it - CPU usage is less than 10%.

[image]

I think I changed every option in the IIS Manager and machine.config and web.config files - nothing seems to have any effect.

Comment: What do you mean that connecting to the application is slow? Do you get timeouts, or errors? More info please. Also the Requests Current in your screenshot isn't showing anything, likely you should be looking at the counters under asp.net V4 or v2 in your counters.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you need to confirm if you have a slowness issue while browsing the site

Check the IIS logs and look for the time-taken field. If the time taken is more than 10 seconds then it is considered as a Slowness.

The slowness might be because of several reasons. It might be because of the Network or might be because something in your code might be causing it.

I suggest you to capture a **Network trace** using Netmon or **WireShark** in case if its a Network related.

If its not Network you can collect a Process dump using **Debug diag 2 update 2** tool.

You can check the below link to collect the dumps and check them and try to find out if there is any slowness:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff420662.aspx